# No route matches [GET] "/admin/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an app that has an admin controller panel to monitor the applications content. How do I create a sign_out route for my admin panel?

My routes.rb:

```
    class MainSite
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == 'www'
    request.subdomain.blank? ||
        request.subdomain == 'what'
  end
end

What::Application.routes.draw do

  post '/rate' => 'rater#create', :as => 'rate'
  # mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  # mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/saas_admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  # devise_for :saas_admins
  devise_for :saas_admins, :path => "admin"
  match "/videos/notify", :to => "saas_admin/videos#notify", via: :post

  namespace "saas_admin", :path => "admin" do
    root :to => "subscriptions#index"
    resources :tags
    resources :taggings
    resources :comments
    resources :app_settings, except: [:new, :destroy]

    resources :subscriptions do
      member do
        post :charge
      end
    end

    resources :accounts
    resources :subscription_plans, :path => 'plans'
    resources :subscription_discounts, :path => 'discounts'
    resources :subscription_affiliates, :path => 'affiliates'

    match "/videos/authorize_upload", :to => "videos#authorize_upload", :via => :post

    scope '/content' do
      root :to => "studios#index", :as => 'content'

      resources :videos, :only => [:create, :update, :index, :show, :destroy] do
      end

      resources :encoded_videos, :only => [:show] do
      end

      resources :studios do
        resources :films do
          resources :clips do
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Routes for the public site
  constraints MainSite do
    # Homepage
    # root :to => "static_pages#home"

    # Static Pages
    get '/faq' => 'static_pages#faq', :as => 'faq'
    get '/webclip', to: 'static_pages#webclip', as: 'webclip'
    get '/my_queue', to: 'users#my_queue', as: 'my_queue'
    get '/learn_more', to: 'static_pages#learn_more', as: 'learn_more'


    # Account Signup Routes
    get '/signup' => 'accounts#plans', :as => 'plans'
    get '/signup/d/:discount' => 'accounts#plans'
    get '/signup/thanks' => 'accounts#thanks', :as => 'thanks'
    get '/signup/create/:discount' => 'accounts#create', :as => 'create', :defaults => { :discount => nil }
    get '/signup/:plan/:discount' => 'accounts#new' #, :as => 'new_account'
    get '/signup/:plan' => 'accounts#new', :as => 'new_account'
    get 'queue_toggle/:id' => 'clips#queue_toggle', as: :queue_toggle
    post 'signup' => 'accounts#new', as: :select_plan
    match 'add_tags' => 'clips#add_tags', via: :post
    resources :clips, :only => [:index, :show] do
      resources :comments
    end

    resources :videos, :only => [:show] do
    end

    resources :encoded_videos, :only => [:show] do
    end

    # Catch-all that just loads views from app/views/content/* ...
    # e.g, http://yoursite.com/content/about -> app/views/content/about.html.erb
    #
    get '/content/:action' => 'content'
  end

  devise_for :users, :path => "user"

  #
  # Account / User Management Routes
  #
  #resources :users
  resources :account_steps
  resource :account do
    resources :users
    member do
      get :dashboard, :thanks, :plans, :canceled
      match 'billing' => "accounts#billing", via: [ :get, :post ]
      match 'plan' => "accounts#plan", via: [ :get, :post ]
      match 'cancel' => "accounts#cancel", via: [ :get, :post ]
      match 'paypal' => "accounts#paypal", via: [ :get, :post ]
      match 'plan_paypal' => "accounts#plan_paypal", via: [ :get, :post ]
      match 'add_organization' => 'accounts#add_organization', via: :put
      match 'add_credit_details' => 'accounts#add_credit_details', via: :put
      match 'update_organization' => 'accounts#update_organization', via: :put
      match 'update_plan' => 'accounts#update_plan', via: :put
    end
  end

  get 'index' => 'static_pages#index', as: :index
  root :to => "static_pages#home"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => "welcome#index"

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I'm guessing it would be something like:

```
get '/admin/sign_out' => 'saasadmin/accounts#sign_out', as: sign_out
```

Any help here would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're using Devise, which should be generating these routes for you. What do you get when you run `rake routes` on the console?

Comment: Ok the problem is I don;t have a devise sessions controller.. here's the route:    destroy_saas_admin_session DELETE   /admin/sign_out(.:format)                                                 devise/sessions#destroy should I create a devise folder, with a sessions controller and destroy action?

Comment: No, your controller is fine. Devise handles that internally. How are you generating your link to the sign_out action? Let me know that and it should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should already have a route defined by Devise. You can create a link with something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'SIGN OUT', destroy_saas_admin_session_path , method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

To add to the accepted answer, you should be aware of the Resourceful routing structure of Rails:

[image]

Rails, by convention, uses this HTTP verb structure to define the routes for your various resources

As you're calling the admin `sessions#destroy` action from your controller, you'll actually need to use the `DELETE` verb, as mentioned above. This is why you were you were getting the `no routes` error for `GET` requests, and is why it worked when you used `method: :delete`